# Querying portal_catalog using typed uuids instead of string uuids

Tags: python, plone, uuid

I'm writing a Plone calendar module for reserving different resources. This module features a calendar whose events are stored in Postgresql. Each calendar is a Dexterity object stored in the ZODB.

To make a link between Plone and Postgresql I naturally turned to the uuid property of the Plone objects. So each uuid in Plone serves as a foreign key in Postgresql, which supports uuid natively.

This worked well for me in the past 6 months until I started using Plone 4.1.4. With it, plone.uuid 1.0.2 was introduced which changes the string representation of uuids from uuids *with* to uuids *without* dashes.

The problem with this change is that I can no longer be certain which representation is going to be used on any given object. Objects created before Plone 4.1.4 contain a differently formatted uuid-string than objects created after.

Long story short, to ensure that my code works with any uuid representation I would love to be able to search by using Python's uuid type.

**So instead of this:**

```
catalog.searchResults(UID='325dc47e-08f9-4fa1-bc18-3944a725adb4')
```

Which returns *different* results than this:

```
catalog.searchResults(UID='325dc47e08f94fa1bc183944a725adb4')
```

**I would love to do this:**

```
from uuid import UUID
catalog.searchResults(UID=UUID('325dc47e-08f9-4fa1-bc18-3944a725adb4'))
```

Which would be *equivalent* to this:

```
catalog.searchResults(UID=UUID('325dc47e08f94fa1bc183944a725adb4'))
```

Does anyone know how I can achieve that kind of independency from the uuid's representation in Plone?

Comment: Hm. Can't you have a function UUID elsewhere which inspects the string, inserts or removes dashes as needed, and then calls `uuid.UUID`? (Astonishing how much breakage Plone generates with every minor update...)

Comment: uuid.UUID actually allows strings with or without dashes. And wherever I can I do make use of that feature by ensuring that the strings I deal with (mostly for JSON) always have a predictable format.


The problem is really that I essentially have to query the catalog with both representations to ensure that I get the object back.

Comment: Would the solution be that you just assume (U)UID is string id and contain any kind of characters? Why are you stripping dashes away?

Comment: I'm stripping the dashes away because plone.uuid went from dashes-included (string) to dashes-removed (hex-string). It left behind a database where both variants must be accounted for when using the catalog's UID search which is string based.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would have to query for both formats; once the UID field has been assigned it should not be changed, really. Your options are thus:

1. Create a method that given a UID returns a tuple with both dashed and non-dashed versions, then use to query the catalog:

   ```
   def queryUID(UID):
       if '-' in UID:
           return (UID.replace('-', ''), UID)
       return (UID, '-'.join([
           UID[:8], UID[8:12], UID[12:16], UID[16:20], UID[20:]]))
   ```

   With that method in place the query simply becomes:

   ```
   catalog.searchResults(UID=queryUID('325dc47e-08f9-4fa1-bc18-3944a725adb4'))
   ```
2. Make your database use dashed versions where the Plone UID has dashes, non-dashed versions where older Plone content still has a UID without dashes. In other words, treat the UID as a opaque string.

   The UIDs in Plone are not going to change in any case, so you won't have to search for the non-dashed version when a dashed version has been generated. Once a UID has been assigned to an object, it never changes, and never will gain the dashes.
3. **NOT recommended** Iterate through your ZODB and replace all UIDs without dashes with the dashed equivalent. This most likely will break anything else linking by UID to those items.

Comment: I shall go ahead with option one. I figure I can take an extra lookup on an index. Thank you!

Comment: It's not an extra lookup on the index; we are asking the index to match on two values instead of one. It's quite efficient. :-)